# How to make phrase sentence about availability for a meeting

Tags: writing

I am writing a formal email to inform my availability for a meeting. I want to write that I am available all week except on Monday morning and Friday morning. Which of the following is correct?

1. I am available all week except on Monday and Friday morning.
2. I am available all week except on Monday morning and Friday morning.
3. I am available all week except on mornings of Monday and Friday.

For option 1, it sounds like I am not available on entire Monday and morning of Friday.
For option 2, using morning twice is repetition.

I would appreciate if someone can comment on or rephrase these options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I have been asked by the OP to post my comment as an answer. Initially I decided not to because it had already been posted by Peter, but as I disagree with part of Peter's answer (see my comment below his answer), I thought it may be useful to post my own suggestions.]

In the light of earlier posts and comments, the selection below tries to illustrate the usage of "not", "neither", "nor", "except" and "un-" as negatives.  But be careful not to use two negatives: note that the option using "neither" omits the "not".

> I am available all week, except on Monday and Friday mornings.
>
> I am not available on Monday morning nor on Friday morning, but otherwise am free.
>
> I am not available on either Monday morning nor Friday morning, but otherwise am free.
>
> I am available on neither Monday morning nor Friday morning, but am free for the rest of the week.
>
> I am available at any time next week, except on the mornings of Monday & Friday.
>
> I am unavailable on both Monday and Friday mornings, but am available at any other time next week.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

> I am available all week except on Monday and Friday morning***s***.

As mentioned in the comments, the "***s***" is very important to signal it applies to both Monday and Friday.
You might also say

> For next week, I am not available on the morning***s*** of Monday and Friday.
>   I am not available on Monday nor Friday morning***s***, but otherwise free.

Comment: I am correct in pointing out that "neither" is missing. CORRECTED VERSION: I am not available on neither Monday nor Friday mornings, but otherwise free.

Comment: Your suggested 'corrected' version is NOT good English.  You should NOT use both "not" & "neither" - they are both negatives and they cancel each other out.  I disagree with Peter's third suggestion, because the "nor" requires the singular (not "morning**s**).

Comment: @NAASI Using " I am not available on neither Monday nor Friday mornings, but otherwise free." is still ambiguous about all day Monday.